# Safari border does not render one side

Tags: css, safari, border, visual-glitch

I have the following CSS / HTML code:

CSS:

```
#buttons a {
 margin: 0 30px;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 padding: 9px 3px;
 -webkit-transition: background 500ms ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: background 500ms ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: background 500ms ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: background 500ms ease-in-out;
 transition: background 500ms ease-in-out;
}
#buttons a span{
 background: #242424;
 font-size: 1.7em;
 color: #fffae6;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 outline: 4px solid #242424;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 5px 40px;
 -webkit-transition: background 500ms ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: background 500ms ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: background 500ms ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: background 500ms ease-in-out;
 transition: background 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

HTML:

`<a class="restaurant_book_button" href="/book"><span>Book Online</span></a>`

How it renders in Safari:
[image: Safari Preview]

How it renders in Chrome:
[image: Chrome Preview]

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try box-sizing with -webkit prefix in span because you are using padding while your span width is 100%.

Comment: so `webkit-box-sizing: border-box;`? It has no effect. Seems to only effect Safari on OSX not Windows.

Comment: try using -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; and it works on every OS

Comment: It does not work (see comment above). The OP problem only effects OSX not windows.

Comment: okay stefan, can you create a fiddle on fiddle.net and check if its working and if not share its URL.

Check this fiddle in your PC - http://jsfiddle.net/MU5xX/

Comment: Same issue in that JSFiddle you linked to.